# Help setting up Memcached in Craft 3

Tags: cache

We want to use Memcached but are struggling to find Craft 3 specific config examples and documentation.

The docs mention several things that seem to lead to dead-ends:

[App config docs here](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/config/app.html#cache-component) show how to configure the component in config/app.php. But in terms of 'enabling' that component, the [docs here](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/changes-in-craft-3.html#memcache) say that `cacheMethod` might need to be used, presumably in config/general.php, but the [link to cacheMethod](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/config/config-settings.html#cachemethod) goes nowhere. Also here in the [changes in v3 article](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/changes-in-craft-3.html#config-settings), is says that `cacheMethod` has "been removed entirely" and instead point readers to [Configuration → Data Caching Config](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/config/#data-caching-config) which is a missing section.

In terms of the server setup, Memcached is enabled and we have 2 nodes/hosts available.

Very confused, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs here are what you need: https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/config/app.html#memcached-example

Which is 99% exactly what Yii uses (since they have an example of using multiple servers): https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-caching-memcache

Comment: See a little more detail form my answer below, received from Craft via email.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the Craft support team who responded here and via email. Some of the docs/links I mentioned have since been corrected.

Here is the salient part of the reply I got from Brandon at Craft:

> "*...So to be clear, the only thing you need to do to get Craft to use
>   Memcached is follow our [Memcached
>   Example](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/config/app.html#memcached-example)
>   from the Application Configuration page. That code should be placed in
>   `config/app.php`, and you will need to customize the config values as
>   needed, and create the `MEMCACHED_USERNAME` and `MEMCACHED_PASSWORD`
>   environment variables (named whatever you want as long as you update
>   the config file appropriately – or you can just hardcode the values
>   but we wouldn’t recommend that).*"

I can confirm that this works.